# WPF ComboBox SelectionItemBox prompt string

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

So I searched in this forum but couldn't find the anwser...

I'm Binding my combobox to a list of users. But when I want to type in it for example a name, some wierd stuff is comming out.

XAML Code:

```
 <ComboBox Name="UserLoginCmbBox" Width="100" IsEditable="True" SelectionChanged="UserLoginCmbBox_SelectionChanged">
          <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Login}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
          </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>
```

Code Behind Code:

```
var users = new List<User>{...} //initialization           
UserLoginCmbBox.ItemsSource = users;
```

When I'm typing in the box only string I can get is:

System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_FE59351B6479342209B496E7D3C3B877DDC51FE15279FFFEF899A5012F85FCBA

I found out that this is what ToString() method returns, but what if I want to use the same list for expamle in another ComboBox where I want to choose the Name or something else?

How can I modify SelectionItemBox? Cause when I tried to use the SelectionItemBoxTemplate to write my own template, an error occured (SelectionItemBoxTemplate has only getter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `DisplayMemberPath`  property to "Login":

```
<ComboBox Name="UserLoginCmbBox" Width="100" IsEditable="True" SelectionChanged="UserLoginCmbBox_SelectionChanged" DisplayMemberPath="Login" />
```

Comment: error: cannot set both ItemTemplate and DisplayMemerPath

Comment: Remove the ItemTemplate as per my sample markup. Just copy it as is.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow